# Log4j extras TimeBasedRollingPolicy equivalent in Log4j2

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am currently using TimeBasedRollingPolicy in Log4j-extras to achieve a uniform naming scheme like so:

```
app.log.2015-10-06-12
app.log.2015-10-06-13
app.log.2015-10-06-14 <- current log
```

The advantage here is that logs are not renamed and I don't lose file handles when I am tailing them and can handle continuous tailing really nicely.

I want to migrate to Log4j2, but I can't find an equivalent of this behavior. RollingFileAppender takes a fileName and filePattern, so I cannot name them with a timestamp, and renaming the files on rollover breaks my tailing code.

Is there any equivalent of the Log4j-extras version or should I stick with it?

Cheers

Comment: No there is no equivalent as yet. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-239.

Comment: That's what I feared, thanks for the response

Comment: Probably too late for you but the issue is resolved now.